# "CKFinder is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

Simple problem (or so it seems).  CKEditor works fine.  But when I dropped in CKFinder, I get the error, "CKFinder is not a constructor" when attempting the follow:

```
var finder = new CKFinder();
finder.basePath = '/includes/ckfinder/';
finder.create();
```

Well, basically it's the first line that causes it, rendering the others pointless.  This is copied/pasted directly from the CK website, minus the change in basepath.

If I do a View Source on the page in Chrome, I can click on the link for ckfinder.js and it opens a tab and shows that it's there.  Yet it just doesn't work.

For the sake of completeness, here's the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: looking at [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_plugins) the error is correct - CKFinder is not a constructor

Comment: so you're saying their example code is wrong? If you look in ckfinder.js, it starts with:  var CKFinder=function(){

Comment: I don't know who "they" are or where your sample code is from - I only looked at the documentation for CKFinder 3 - but it may be that the documentation I found was for something unrelated to your issue - as it mentions CKfinder plugins rather than just ckfinder - perhaps if you provided a link to where you got the code from?

Comment: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ColdFusion/Integration/JavaScript  The version it gave me is 2.6.2.1.  It seems the only way to get v3 is to use the php or .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  It wasn't clear at all when I downloaded the trial that it's serving either v3 or v2 of the code.  I had installed v3 and was using the JavaScript API, which is v2.  Once I put the v2 code in place, the error went away.